# Grails 2.5, Gorm, Date Error

Tags: date, grails, grails-orm

I created an employee domain class using `java.util.Date` for a birthday attribute. That was mapped to Datetime (date + time which I don't want) in my MySQL database. So I tried `java.sql.Date` which results in the right datatype in my table, unfortunately there is an error in my Grails application saying:

```
Could not find matching constructor for: java.sql.Date(java.util.Date)
```

domain class:

```
package sample

class Mitarbeiter {

    String name
    java.sql.Date geburtstag

    static constraints = {
       name()
       birthday()
    }
}
```

controller:

```
package sample

class MitarbeiterController {

    def scaffold = Mitarbeiter
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the controller scaffolding is not capable of matching the 2 dates.

What happens if you define the mapping like this (docs are [here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html)):

```
class Mitarbeiter {

    String name
    Date geburtstag

    static constraints = {
       name()
       birthday()
    }

    static mapping = {
        geburtstag sqlType: "date"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, That worked! Datatype in mySQL is now Date, but in the view (grails generated) it still shows date + time (00:00:00 MESZ)

Comment: Glad to help - I suspect you'll need to amend the scaffolding if you want custom formatting of your field.  You can always run one of the `grails generate-view` or `generate-all` commands (http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/ref/Command%20Line/generate-views.html) to create a statically scaffolded view which you can then customise.  If you want a picker to set the date, you can configure that as shown in the docs here: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.x/ref/Tags/datePicker.html

Comment: format("yyyy-mm-dd") in the generated view did the job. Thanks!